# How to get the value of a textbox and pass it to another component in Angular2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently trying to find a way to extract a value from one textbox and pass that value to a title of a dropdownbox.

***Textbox***

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" id="sDate" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly="readonly" value =" {{calendar | date:'dd MMM y'}} " #sDate/>
</div>
```

**Dropdown**

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>
{{title}}<img src="images/dateicon.png">
</button>
```

**Typescript**

`this.title = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("sDate" + this.id)).value;`

Comment: What is thet typescript for? is it the dropdown's one or the textbox's one? Also, you should never use document selector in angular2, use `sDate.nativeElement` instead

Comment: @Supamiu I have edited the qn. I have managed to pass the value to the other textbox. Thank you for your reply :)